# How I can show a Variable Valor in to a h1 in html and js

Tags: javascript, html, var

I'm new to coding things, and I want to learn a lot, so I found Stackoverflow, to solve my question...

The code I have is:

```
<h1 class="Result" id="result">0</h1>
```

Now, I do a basic JS File:

```
const number = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById('result');
```

And, now I don't know what to do, to display it in the h1, if someone can help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `elem.textContent = number;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some of the ways you can dynamically add the value.

`document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = number;`

`document.getElementById('result').innerText = number;`

`document.getElementById('result').textContent = number;`

Answer (score 0):

You have an h1 with an id of 'result', side note always have different id and class name so you dont confuse yourself.

`<h1 class="Result" id="result">0</h1>`

For your javascript:

`var elem = document.getElementById('result')`

So now that you have placed the content of the h1 inside a variable you can display it using:

`console.log(elem)`

The reason your code didn't work was that you didn't use the console.log of a variable to display the content inside the variable.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to grab the h1 tag using the document.getElementById() method like you did.

Than you use the innerHTML property to display text.

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>
javaScript example
</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">
click to see message
</button>
<h1 Id="message" class="message">
</h1>
<script>
function myFuntion(){
var message = "hello, how are you\?";
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
  
First we created a button that has a function attach to it, than we create an function that will store the message. When the button is clicked, the message will show in the h1 tag.
Good luck!
```